# Use one object to reduce another using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a need to use the information in one object to determine which information in another to include.
The idea being that `display` controls what should be included, while `alarms` contains all the alarms in all their states.

```
display={
  0: false,
  1: true,
  2: true,
  3: true,
  ACK: false,
  MASKED: false,
  SHELVED: false,
}

alarms={inAlarm:{ 0:["A"],
                  1:["B"],
                  2:["C"],
                  3:["D"],
                },
        latched:{ 1:[],
                  2:["C"],
                  3:[],
                },
        connectionError:["E"],
        ACK:["F"],
        SHELVED:["G"],
        MASKED:[],
}
```

Everything in latched shoudl always be included, but the others can be turned on/off.
So in this case I want to yield a single array which should be: `["B","C","D"]`. I'm looking for a neat lodash way to do it, or even an efficient and elegant standard js version - but preferably something that doesn't need helper functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending @Fonty's answer which will not work for keys 0, 1, 2, 3 in display object becuase for them the `inAlarm` key's value neeed to be picked:

```
var result = [];
for (var key in display) {
   if (!display[key]) {
     continue;
   }
   if (isNaN(key)) { // for non-numeric keys
      result = _.union(result, alarms[key]);
   } else { // for numeric keys
      result = _.union(result, alarms.inAlarm[key]);
   }
}
result = _.union(result, _.union(_.flatten(_.values(alarms.latched))));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice. Although I will still move the inAlarm values up one level as it became quite useful to have everything at the same level for other purposes later down the track.

Answer (score -1):

So, while it may not be the most elegant solution and it's not straight up lodash, it's not too bad.
The best solution was to not include the `inAlarm` key, but rather pull those values out to the top level. Then I can simply do:

```
let tempA=[]

for(var key in display){
  if(display[key]){
    tempA=_.union(tempA, alarms[key])
  }
}

tempA=_.union(tempA, _.flatten(_.union(_.values(alarms.LATCHED))))
```

This seems quick and non intensive, even if I had a few thousand entries.